# Remove an issue from an Epic

Tags: jira, greenhopper

Using Jira with GreenHopper.

The issue is not visible on the SCRUM board because it was closed in a past sprint.
The issue should not have been added to the Epic in the first place.
We want to keep our Epics clean and remove tasks that do not concern it, even after closing them.

The only way to remove a task from an Epic, as far as I understand it, is to do it from the SCRUM board, in the 'Work' view, in the right side task detail-at-a-glance panel, by clicking the [X] button in the Epic's label.

Considering that:

- The issue is not displayed in the SCRUM board;
- We do not have access to the server to perform SQL (and wouldn't want to go down that path);

Then:

- Is there a way to remove the task from the Epic from
- --> The Epic issue screen?
- --> The issue screen (the issue in the Epic)?
- Is there a way to actually display a closed/past issue in the SCRUM board?
- Is there any other way of achieving my goal I wouldn't have mentioned here?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can add the Epic Link field to an edit screen for the issue in question and then edit the issue as usual in JIRA, not JIRA Agile

Comment: That actually was the problem. The "Epic Link" field was not visible in the ticket screen. That is a mistake from whoever configured this project.

Comment: A quick way of changing that is to use `.` while vieweing the issue and then type and select `Epic link`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can remove the issues from an epic by editing the issues and changing the issue type from epic to another type.

In order to display closed/past issues on the SCRUM board you could configure your scrum board and produce a quick filter to show past issues using the correct syntax if you have access to these. Another way would be to find these through the issues tab. Here you there are drop downs to help find the issues you want. You would be interested in the "status" tab. If you are invovled in multiple projects then use the "project" tab to just look for clsoed issues for that particular project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about removing an issue FROM an Epic, not transforming an Epic into a normal task.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Is there a way to remove the task from the Epic from

---

> - The issue screen?

Navigate to the Issues Tab and just remove the Epic from the Epic Field

> - The Epic issue screen?

This is not possible

---

---

> 2: Is there a way to actually display a closed/past issue in the SCRUM board?

---

Yes there is, just create a new row and a new JQL Filter, which finds the closed issues in the specific sprint, then map them to the row.

---

---

> 3: Is there any other way of achieving my goal I wouldn't have
>   mentioned here?

---

There are many other ways to achieve what you want, like writing or adding a Plugin, which gives you the functionality, creating new filters etc. etc.